# Git: Internal error: refs/remotes/origin/master is not a valid packed reference

Tags: windows, git

I am attempting to clone a git repository on a Windows network drive, but the process fails. It first throws a `internal error: refs/remotes/origin/master is not a valid packed reference`, and then repeatedly relates that it failed to unlink an index file.

```
x:\code\source> git clone x:\code\repos\project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
done.
error: internal error: refs/remotes/origin/master is not a valid packed reference!
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update the ref 'HEAD': 
  Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistent object d34950c3faee46d8a7f3b8e7950b04fcc5da9d1c
Unlink of file 'project/.git/objects/pack/pack-....idx' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

I am able to clone without issue to a local drive from a bare repo on the network drive, but am unable to clone to a network drive.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When cloning *to* a mapped network drive using a standard Windows command prompt, you need to preface the *from* path with `file://`.

E.g.,

```
git clone file://x:\code\repos\project.git
```

or, if there are spaces,

```
git clone "file://x:\my code\repos\project.git"
```

You cannot, however, do the same when specifying the target.

```
** DOESN'T WORK **
git clone file://x:\code\repos\project.git file://y:\code\source\project
```

Instead,

```
cd y:\code\source
git clone file://x:\code\repos\project.git project
```

Comment: Exactly what my problem was! The older version of Git worked without requiring a `file://` prefix though.

Comment: How would you resolve this error through a GUI? I've had this appear in "git extensions" and it doesn't accept URI paths.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers who are trying to use GitExtensions and getting this error: David C's answer works for our purposes as well, and you can type in `file://` before the 'Repo to clone' location name.

This error arises when the Repo to clone and destination directory are both on a local network drive.

[image]