# How to git clone from *local bare* repository

Tags: git, git-clone, git-bare

Say I have a bare repository on my local machine at `./new-bare.git`.
What is the correct way to clone it to another location on my machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone from another directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045061/git-clone-from-another-directory)

Comment: @frlan Different question- I'm referring to cloning from bare repositories, as emphasized in the header

Comment: bare / non-bare should not make any difference

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no difference in cloning from a not bare repository:

```
/tmp> mkdir foo
/tmp> git init --bare foo 
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/foo/
/tmp> git clone /tmp/foo /tmp/baa
Cloning into '/tmp/baa'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
```

Comment: I'm was a little confused with the use of `--local` but I guess your answer works for my simple case. 10X

Answer (score 8):

```
git clone path_to_new-bare.git new_destination
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this appears to only work when the folder name ends with `.git` (as in the example). Apart from that, much nicer than the accepted answer, thanks :)