# Trouble cloning local git repository with Git Bash on Windows

Tags: git

I have been trying to clone a local Git repository for about an hour now.  The repository is on a Windows 7 server, and I am trying to make a clone right next to it.  My workflow is to clone the repository, make some changes, and test.  If all is good, I pull the changes back into the original repository and delete the clone.

I am using Git Bash (part of Tortoise Git).  The repository is on a mapped network drive.  I was having some issues cloning because of the drive, so I read this:

[git clone from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045061/git-clone-from-another-directory)

I then did the following:

```
spearsc@BB-DIGI-SPEARSC MINGW64 /r/nasenv (master)
$ git clone . /r/nasenv_copy
Cloning into 'R:/nasenv_copy'...
done.
error: internal error: refs/remotes/origin/master is not a valid packed reference!
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update ref 'refs/heads/master': trying to write ref 'refs/heads/master' with nonexistent object 1fa512cca95695979f35515f1ea69c391d214544
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The resulting repo is empty except for a .git folder.  From past experience, I thought the issue was the mapped drive (in this case R).

I tried the following:

```
spearsc@BB-DIGI-SPEARSC MINGW64 /r/nasenv (master)
$ git clone . file://r:\nasenv_copy
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'file://r:nasenv_copy': Invalid argument

spearsc@BB-DIGI-SPEARSC MINGW64 /r/nasenv (master)
$ git clone . file://r:/nasenv_copy
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'file://r:/nasenv_copy': Invalid argument

spearsc@BB-DIGI-SPEARSC MINGW64 /r/nasenv (master)
$ git clone . file://r/nasenv_copy
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'file://r/nasenv_copy': Invalid argument

spearsc@BB-DIGI-SPEARSC MINGW64 /r/nasenv (master)
$ git clone . file://R:/nasenv_copy
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'file://R:/nasenv_copy': Invalid argument
```

None of these work.  This is really frustrating because I did do this last week.  I'm not sure if I just forgot or if a change in the main repo is causing this.

Comment: Cloning from the network drive to my desktop works!  This is fine for my workflow, but I still do not know why I can clone to the network drive.

Comment: `git clone . file://r/nasenv_copy` is odd. It means to clone the repo `.`, the current folder, into a new directory `file://r/nasenv_copy`.

Comment: I was wondering if I should just drop the period.