# Read code in gitlab via shell

Tags: git, shell

I recently installed gitlab on my server, the aim for me is to write scripts on my laptop and easily push them into the server.

I found where data is stored, I left the default value, which is /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/username, but I can't see my files in there, it seems I can do nothing from my shell session.

Is there a command I should run to assemble files into usable scripts or is there a more graceful way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Entering to Gitlab's internal repo storage seems risky and should be done only when is strictly necessary. You should try entering to Gitlab webpage through a browser. There it will show you how to manage repositories, including cloning and pushing, and the vast amount of features Gitlab provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is storing your files in its internal (binary) database, called a [bare repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server). If you want to see those files in their normal text form on the machine hosting the repository, you can clone it locally. This is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045596/3195526) and in the [git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS).

Comment: Thanks ! Cloning it locally is a great solution, it will resolve my problem.
And again thank you for providing details about git storage system, I was wondering how it was done exactly.