# How to escape spaces in path to local git repo when specifying dependency in requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, pip

How can I specify a local git repo as a dependency in requirements.txt so that I can install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt`? The issue is not that I am unable to install or clone from that location, but how to escape the spaces in the path to the repo directory **in the requirements.txt**. To be completely clear, both cloning and pip installing work by enclosing the path in `"`, it only fails with `pip install -r`.

I have tried

- `git+"K:/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git"`
- `git+git://"K:/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git"`
- `git+git:"//K:/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git"`
- `git+"git://K:/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git"`
- `"K:/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git"`
- `git+file://K:/my/path\ with/lots\ of/spaces/repo/.git`

But in every case I receive the error `ValueError: No closing quotation`.

If I try to escape the spaces with `\` it is interpreted as a Windows Path separator and fails.

**EDIT**:

So the following works:

`pip install git+file:///"k/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git/"`

However, when I put the exact same thing into my `requirements.txt` (without `pip install`, of course), I get the `ValueError: No closing quotation`. Any ideas on how to solve this would be highly appreciated. Is it something I should open an issue with pip for?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support). You need a branch name at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Comment: If I specify a branch name I get the same error. I am able to clone the repo with `git clone "K:/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git"`. How is this a duplicate? It's not about a specific branch at all.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues not a duplicate: this deals with a local file path, not something from github or bitbucket (which all the answers on that question show).

Comment: Is this the only line in your `requirements.txt` file, or are there other lines (with possible quotes) in that file?

Comment: @00 there are more lines in there, but all of them are "normal" dependencies from pypi so without quotes.

Comment: try `git+file:///k/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git/`, *without* quotes. The quotes are necessary to escape the shell breaking up the path by whitespace, but Python, and thus pip, when reading the requirements file, will read the whole line as a single string, and not break it by space.

Comment: Aside: that is the weirdest path I've seen in a while: starts with `/k/` a the root, and has a hidden subdirectory `.git/` which apparently contains the actual repository, even if the directory above that is called `repo/` (I can only assume there is also a `.svn/` subdir somewhere). Usually, the `.git/` subdirectory is reserved for git, and implicit when installing directory from a git repository.

Comment: There is no `.svn` directory anywhere, this is indeed a `git` repo. This is a Windows path and I "converted" it according to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045061/git-clone-from-another-directory) question. If there is a better/more concise way, I'm all ears.

Comment: Without quotes the path is broken at the first space, so it tries to clone from `git+file:/k/my/path`.

Comment: You mean broken when used inside the requirements file? Because testing on my side doesn't show that.

Comment: Yes, without quotation marks, so `requirements.txt` contains `git+file:///k/my/path with/lots of/spaces/repo/.git/`. After `pip install -r requirements.txt`: `ERROR: Command "git clone -q git+file:///k/my/path 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-1gzemqen'" failed with error code 128 in None`

Comment: I wonder if this is something intrinsic to Windows then; I could only test it on a Mac, where this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quoting user chrahunt here who answered to the [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7234) on GitHub.

> The handling of quotes when pip is executed directly is governed by your shell. In Bash, for example, non-nested pairs of quotes are stripped and their contents concatenated with what comes before/after to create each argument.
>
> Requirements files, on the other hand, are read as-is by optparse and no special quote handling or stripping takes place.
>
> That said, in this case when trying to provide a URL, the non-valid URL characters (like space) must be percent-encoded (space is %20).

So in my case, I had to change the requirements.txt entry to `git+file:///k/my/path%20with/lots%20of/spaces/repo/.git/` and it worked. This should not be platform dependent and %20 should work everywhere.