# Is it dangerous to open or clone a Git repository from an untrusted source

Tags: git, github-desktop

I was sent a Git repository (the .git folder) from an untrusted source.

I want to take a look at it with GitHub Desktop that I have installed, but I don't know enough about the inner workings of Git to know if this is dangerous. Is it safe like opening a text file with notepad, or potentially more dangerous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** cloning is safer than receiving a `.git` directory.

**Details:**

Do not blindly trust a repo someone gives you by handing you the `.git` directory. Presumably if someone gives you a repo, you're going to do *something* with it.

It won't hurt anything just sitting on your machine, but **it's possible it could hurt you if you *use* the repo.** The biggest concern is Git hooks, which are, by default, found in the folder: `.git/hooks`. Hooks can run arbitrary scripts when you type regular Git commands like `commit`, `rebase`, `merge`, `push`, etc. The location of those hooks can also be changed by using a config setting, which is found in the file `.git/config`. Also found in that config may be Git aliases, which you may want to inspect to make sure nothing funky is going on. Note that the config file can also include other configs files as well, so you'd have to see if any others are being included.

If you're worried about it, I believe it would be safe to simply [clone that repo to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21045061/184546). AFAIK that shouldn't bring in any of the customized configs or hooks. When you clone the repo, you should end up in the state as described in [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74200458/184546).

Comment: Yup. Best thing to do if you need the history is just put it on your machine and then clone *from* it, using the default (or your own) repo template.

Answer (score 2):

A Git repository effectively "contains" some files in a sort of dehydrated form. When you check out the main branch of the repository, they are rehydrated — that is, you now "have" those files. That's all that happens.

The "danger" is therefore just like the danger of having *any* file that you aren't sure about — no more, and no less. The fact that you received these files wrapped up in a Git repository is irrelevant.

For example, can a virus or similar spread from the mere *presence* of a certain file on your computer? If so, then there is that same danger in this instance. If the danger comes more from *opening* a file (e.g., looking at it in Microsoft Word, or running it as an executable), then if one of the files is that kind of file, there would be that same danger if *you* were to open it. And so on.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying. With your example a Microsoft Word document could be dangerous if it contains a malicious macro that gets run automatically when opened by Word. I suppose my question is, might the GitHub Desktop program automatically run "something" malicious in a similar manner.

Comment: My point is: No. It doesn't "open" anything. But you might. It's no different from receiving any other folder full of stuff.

Comment: This is a good answer for cloning, but it should probably be distinguished from receiving a .git directory, which I addressed in a separate answer.